# field between certain time do something

Tags: php, drupal

Im using drupal. I have a field which displays a countdown timer. im trying to do something when the time is between 10 and 1 seconds left. Im quite new to php so I'm looking for a starting point.

So how do I express in php, When the timer on the form on nid is between 1 and 10 seconds do something?

Thanks for any help

Edited -
I have Ajax refreshing the page every second to update the timer etc. 
How can I get something to happen at a random time between 1 and 10 seconds, does the page have to be being viewed?

Comment: Note that PHP can only do something to the page if it's actually generating the page in that 1-10 second range. Otherwise, you'll need some javascript to modify the page on the client-side.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this.  PHP doesn't actually "see" whats going on in the webpage, it only generates the HTML content.  If you want PHP to "see" parts of the page, you'll have to use something like javascript to relay it.

Comment: The answer *may* depend on some specifics for "do something."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edited - I have Ajax refreshing the page every second to update the timer etc. How can I get something to happen at a random time between 1 and 10 seconds, does the page have to be being viewed?

The page has to be being viewed in order for anything to happen, since PHP and and Javascript are only loaded upon page view.

Furthermore, PHP cannot see or manipulate the page after the page loads initially without AJAX. You'd have to use AJAX with Javascript to access the timer and see what time it says. Then you can generate a random number between 1 and 10 and say "if(current_count == rand_time) { ... do something ... }", and that would have to be in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to perform your action. PHP cannot handle this stuff because PHP requires a request to be sent to the server and response is rendered on the browser which takes up quite some time and time tracking so closely is not possible.